# Replace (international phone number) in a pandas column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to replace all international phone numbers in a python column (mostly European ones).

Currently I have:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].replace('^(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?$',r'\Tel', regex=True)
```

I am following this well-known question on here: [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

But somehow, this phone number: `04265-217866` is not reached by this. Any ideas how to tune it?

The data in df['A'] is german text data and looks like:

```
df['A']
Sehr geehrter Herr... Mit freundlichen Grüßen 0049-172 387898
Ich hoffe ich konnte helfen 0021 111789
Sie erreichen mich unter 04265-217866
```

The desired outcome in this case would be:

```
Sehr geehrter Herr... Mit freundlichen Grüßen Tel
Ich hoffe ich konnte helfen Tel
Sie erreichen mich unter Tel
```

My phone numbers are European(german) numbers:

```
0049 231 184989
+49 231 184989
0049231184989
0231 - 184989
```

and more

Comment: what does the data in `df['A']` look like? can we take a peek?

Comment: The regex does not match numbers like yours. It is not clear what your phone number requirements are. So, no idea what regex you need.

Comment: try this one:
^011(9[976]\d|8[987530]\d|6[987]\d|5[90]\d|42\d|3[875]\d|
2[98654321]\d|9[8543210]|8[6421]|6[6543210]|5[87654321]|
4[987654310]|3[9643210]|2[70]|7|1)\d{0,14}$

You can replace the \ds with [0-9] if Your regex syntax doesn't support \d.